How to solve this nonconvex problem in python
I have the following problem to solve
minimize $$\sum_{i=1}^I\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{i,k}.$$
The constraints are as follows:
$$\sum_{i=1}^I\sum_{j=1}^J\ln(c+x_{i,k}A_{i,j,k})\geqslant B_k,\forall k,$$ and
$$\sum_{k=1}^Kx_{i,k}\leq1,\forall i.$$
where $c$ and $A_{i,j,k}$ and $B_{k}$ are known (inputs).
I am not sure what solver is capable of solving the problem in Python (for example) because it seems like it is nonconvex problem. Do you have any idea how to use cvxpy or any other tool to solve the problem, especially when $I=500$, $K=50$ and $J=50$.

As for the cvxpy, have you read the docs/tutorials? As for alternative tools, you may check for Ipopt, algencan, nlopt, and bonmin.

Out of curiosity, is there more you can say about the known constants? For example, is $c > 0$ and are the $A_{i, j, k}$ all non-negative? Additionally, do you also intend each $x_{i, k}$ to be non-negative?

Yes sorry about that. $0\le x_{i,k}\le1$, and all inputs are non-negative.

This is a convex problem: the objective is convex, the domain of $x$ is convex and the nonlinear constraint is $\sum \sum -\ln(...) \le -B_k$, which is convex ($-\ln$ is convex).

@zdm Further question, do you have a ball park for the largest value of $A_{i, j, k}/c$ you see? I'm curious if this ratio is really larger or really small.

@CharlieVanaret Thank you. Do you know how to model cvxpy to solve it.

@spektr The value of $A_{i,j,k}/c$ is large, we can say in the range $[10^5, 10^9]$.
